# How to get live data from WorkManager in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I am trying to make an API call from the `doWork()` method of **WorkManager**. I receive `MutableLiveData` with a list from the response. How do I set this complex object as an output from WorkManager?

Please find below the implementation for the same:

```
class FetchWorkManager(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters): Worker(context, params) {
    var postInfoLiveData: LiveData<List<PostInfo>> = MutableLiveData()

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        fetchInfoFromRepository()
        // Setting output data
        val data = Data.Builder()
            .putAll(postInfoLiveData)
            //.put("liveData", postInfoLiveData)
            .build()
        return Result.success(data)
    }


    fun fetchInfoFromRepository() {
        val retrofitRepository = RetrofitRepository()
        postInfoLiveData = retrofitRepository.fetchPostInfoList()
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: You can store response list data in `Room Database` even if your app is running out from background

Comment: But how to set LiveData received from web service in doWork() method. For primitive objects it is fine. Is there a way to set custom objects likes LiveData as output data

Answer (score 4):

i am not sure but it should be like this :)

```
workManager?.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(oneTimeWorkRequest.id)
                ?.observe(this, Observer {
                    if (it?.state == null)
                        return@Observer
                    when (it.state) {
                        State.SUCCEEDED -> {
                            val successOutputData = it.outputData

                        }
                        State.FAILED -> {
                            val failureOutputData = it.outputData

                        }
                    }
                })
```

Comment: But how to set LiveData received from web service in doWork() method. For primitive objects it is fine. Is there a way to set custom objects likes LiveData as output data

Answer (score 2):

It is not intended behaviour to return result from `Worker` with `LiveData` member. The result from the `Worker` should be returned as a return value of [`startWork`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker.html#startWork()) method. To construct `Result` object with some data [`ListenableWorker.Result.success`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker.Result.html#success(androidx.work.Data)) method can be used.

```
const val WORKER_RESULT_INT = "WORKER_RESULT_INT"

class WorkerWithOutput(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, params) {
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        // do some work
        return Result.success(Data.Builder().putInt(WORKER_RESULT_INT, 123).build())
    }
}
```

And to get this data from outside one of [`getWorkInfoXXX`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html#getWorkInfoById(java.util.UUID)) methods should be used.

```
fun getResult(context: Context, owner: LifecycleOwner, id: UUID) {
    WorkManager.getInstance(context)
            .getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(id)
            .observe(owner, Observer {
                if (it.state == WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    val result = it.outputData.getInt(WORKER_RESULT_INT, 0)
                    // do something with result
                }
            })
}
```

Activity or fragment can be passed as `LifecycleOwner` (depending on your case). [`WorkRequest.getId`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkRequest.html#getId()) is used to get `id` of the work.

It is worth noting that there is [`ListenableWorker.setProgressAsync`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker.html#setProgressAsync(androidx.work.Data)) which also can be useful in such circumstances.

Comment: But how to set LiveData received from web service in doWork() method. For primitive objects it is fine. Is there a way to set custom objects likes LiveData as output data

Comment: @Android_programmer_office Unfortunately it's not possible to put `LiveData` oject into `Data`.  It is not even possible to put `Parcleable` into `Data` (unlike into `Bundle`). `Data` class is designed so that it can be persisted into database - this requirement restricts the set of data types which can be put into `Data` object.

Comment: `WorkManager` is not desinged for querying data, it is intended for background task independent of UI workflow. This [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/#choosing_the_right_solution_for_your_work) may help to better understand its purposes. For querying data in background it's better to use `RxJava` or kotlin coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would work since I have not tried it yet. and I know it is a late answer but I would encourage you to try to use CoroutineWorker as below:

```
class MyWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters):
    CoroutineWorker(context, params){
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {

      val data = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
         // you can make network request here (best practice?)
         return@withContext fetchInfoFromRepository()
         // make sure that fetchInfoFromRepository() returns  LiveData<List<PostInfo>>
      }
    
      /* Then return it as result with a KEY (DATA_KEY) to use in UI. */
      val result = workDataOf(DATA_KEY to data)
      return Result.success(result)
   }
}
```

ref: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/coroutineworker